# Drag menu shows subitems from Menu at the time of dragging

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using draggable menu where i drag menuitem from menu and create a dynamic control in web page

But at the time of dragging it shows menu with subitems if that menu has subitems.
It should visible only draggable menu item not subitem. Here is a screen shot how it looks like.

[image]

**JQUERY :**

```
$(".selector li").draggable({           
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        zIndex: 100,

    });
```

**EDIT:**

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oy0cm3me/6/)**

Comment: Can you please create a Jsfiddle of the issue you are having?

Comment: Use events.

start: function( event, ui ) {
             ui.helper.find('ul').hide();
         }

Comment: plz close this question by accepting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use events.

```
start: function( event, ui ) { ui.helper.find('ul').hide(); }
```